# Are questions about argument debunking on topic?

Tags: discussion

I wonder if questions asking *about* proper argumentation are on topic? I.e., questions concerning fallacies and argument construction or debunking.

What I mean is that Q&A here are mostly formatted as "claim -> support of a claim / debunking of a claim". Can questions like "which fallacy does this statement contain?" and similar be asked here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they would not be on topic.

The site is about "examining the evidence behind claims" and not "examining claims". Typically if you are looking for a logic-based answer or examination the best site could be [Philosophy](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com).